# JAX-RS Client API async request

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, jersey-client

I am trying to use the JAX-RS Client API to request a resource through HTTP GET, by using the following code: (I used jersey-client v2.12 and also resteasy-client v3.0.8.Final to test the implementation)

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback;

public class StackOverflowExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.target("http://example.com/").request().async().get(new InvocationCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void completed(String s) {
        System.out.println("Async got: " + s);
      }

      @Override
      public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("Async failure...");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

As I expected the String is printed almost immediately. But the process keeps running about one minute, although there isn't any code that should be executed.

The JAX-RS spec just says that we should use the `InvocationCallback` and nothing else that matters to my issue. But even if I use a `Future` the same effect happens. I also tested, if this has something to do with a timeout, which was very unlikely and wrong. The debugger shows that there are some threads running namely `DestroyJavaVM` and `jersey-client-async-executor-0` or `pool-1-thread-1` in the case of resteasy.

Do you have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is allways helpful to consult the JavaDoc. Concerning my issue [it says](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html):

> Clients are heavy-weight objects that manage the client-side communication infrastructure. Initialization as well as disposal of a Client instance may be a rather expensive operation. It is therefore advised to construct only a small number of Client instances in the application. Client instances must be properly closed before being disposed to avoid leaking resources.

If I close the client properly everything is working as expected.

```
public class StackOverflowExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    // request here
    client.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: and when exactly are you closing your client, if your call is async ? because if you just close it like that, then you will be probably not be able to make the call because you dont know whether the async call has been finished.

So you need to be sure that the call has been finished and then close the client, but how do you do that ? In your completed(...) and failed(..) method ?